# changing UIButton image after click a button

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

```
    @IBAction func play(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if player.isPlaying == true {
            let myImage = UIImage(named:"stop")
            sender.setImage(myImage, for: .normal)

            if player.isPlaying == false {
            (sender as AnyObject).setImage(UIImage(named: "play"), for: .normal)}
        }

}
```

after I click the button, Its button image changes but it never goes back afterwards. how should I make it go back to the original button image?

Comment: when you need this `but it never goes back afterwards.` I mean your video played completely or else

Comment: yes.. when you want to change image back

Comment: Your second line of set image named "play" will never be executed because isPlaying state is true. Make two separate if statements instead of nested if or change the image in else

Comment: if player.isPlaying == true {
                let myImage = UIImage(named:"stop")
                sender.setImage(myImage, for: .normal)
            }
            if player.isPlaying == false {
                (sender as AnyObject).setImage(UIImage(named: "play"), for: .normal)}

Comment: I made them seperated but it never goes back.

Answer (score 4):

I partially understand your question, try this

```
@IBAction func play(_ sender: UIButton) {
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named:player.isPlaying ? "stop" : "play")  , for: .normal)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@IBAction func play(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if player.isPlaying == true {
            let myImage = UIImage(named:"stop")
            sender.setImage(myImage, for: .normal)
         } else {
            sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "play"), for: .normal)
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't stop the player when you press the button, isPlaying will always be true. So first if conditions works.

```
 @IBAction func play(_ sender: UIButton) {


  if player.isPlaying == true {
     player.stop()
     sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"stop"), for: .normal)
  }

  if player.isPlaying == false {
     player.play()
     sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "play"), for: .normal)
  }

}
```

Comment: how you can set image for AnyObject?